# Unable to locate package `tizonia-all`

Tags: linux, debian-bullseye, music-streaming

I'm trying to install the Tizonia cloud music player on Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye). I've gone past a few issues already, but now I'm stuck at this stage:

```
E: Unable to locate package tizonia-all
Oops. Something went wrong!
```

The command I'm using is as follows:

```
curl -kL https://github.com/tizonia/tizonia-openmax-il/raw/master/tools/install.sh | bash
```

I've looked it up and fell on this GitHub issue: https://github.com/tizonia/tizonia-openmax-il/issues/640 However, that doesn't apply to me, since my machine's architecture is amd64. Indeed, running `uname -m` returns `x86_64`.

Comment: You're right, it isn't the same problem as in your link. That said, the proposed solution - installing the snap version - is worth exploring.

Comment: Fair. Do you know of a way I can remove all APT packages that were installed past a certain date and time? Before proceeding with anything else, I'd like to clean up any unnecessary dependencies that were installed. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: According to their own instructions it's as simple as: `sudo apt-get -y remove --purge tizonia-all && sudo apt-get -y autoremove` (you can and probably should avoid the "-y" argument).

Comment: @ChanganAuto Unfortunately, given that `tizonia-all` was never installed, (because that package could not be found) running `sudo apt-get -y remove --purge tizonia-all` returns: `E: Unable to locate package tizonia-all`.

Comment: So there's nothing to uninstall.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I'm not quite sure. Take a look at the install script: https://github.com/tizonia/tizonia-openmax-il/blob/master/tools/install.sh A bunch of stuff is getting installed before it even checks whether `tizonia-all` is available. Thanks for you comment.

Comment: Yes, it install as dependencies a couple of python dev libraries and a spotify library. Do you need those outside of using the program you were trying to install? Probably not. Do they interfere with something? No, they don't and the space it takes is negligible. Can you and should you remove them? It depends and no, not really. If anything is "orphaned" you should be able to remove with `sudo apt autoremove`. Do NOT try to manually remove them especially the python ones. One simple mistake can make easily break the system for good.

Comment: If later you decide to try the snap version all it needs will be installed in the snap container.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Perfect. I'll take your advice on that, then. Thank you for taking the time to help me out; it's very appreciated. I'll try the Snap package shortly and post it as an answer it that works. God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple and just install the Snap package:

```
sudo snap install tizonia
```